# Is it possible to disable screenshare if someone's got meterpreter shell on your PC?

Tags: network, windows, metasploit, reverse-shell

If hypothetically there was a meterpreter shell installed on your pc, are there security features or ways to harden a Windows laptop to prevent the hacker from using the screen share command to spy on you?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just screenshare? Everything else is ok, but you just don't want screen share?

Comment: Meterpreter is well-known. An offline virus scan with a LiveCD would detect it.

Comment: Block all traffic to anything but your router using Windows Firewall.

Comment: What about not letting meterpreter run?